# Hoe to configure .net application, which is written in .net2, to use .net 6 runtime on IIS server?

Tags: .net

I am working on .net application which is written in .net 2 and it is running on IIS window server 2016.

I am planning to configure .net application, which is written in .net 2, to use .net 6 at runtime on IIS window server 2016. I have installed .net 6 runtime in my machine.

I am not sure is it feasible option or not. I am new in .net world, so i dont have clear idea.
I tried to change 'TargetFramework' flag in 'website' file and web.config, but it seems like it is not working.